# Error in AWS ECR: "##[error]Error: Input required: sourceImageId"

Tags: azure-devops, amazon-ecr

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering an issue with AWS ECR, and I could use some help in resolving it. When running my workflow, I'm getting the following error message:

`##[error]Error: Input required: sourceImageId`

I've checked my configuration, but I'm unable to identify the source of the problem. Here are some details about my setup:

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
trigger:
  - Development
resources:
  - repo: self
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
  - group: Development

stages:
  - template: templates/buildAndPush_identityapi.yml
  - template: templates/buildAndPush_administrationapi.yml
```

**buildAndPush_identityapi.yml**

```
stages:
- stage: Docker_Identity_API
  displayName: 'Build and Push Identity API image to AWS ECR'
  jobs:
  - job: Build_and_Push
    displayName: 'Build and push docker image'
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: 'Build an Image'
      inputs:
        command: build
        dockerfile: '$(IDENTITY_API_PATH)/Dockerfile'
        buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
        repository: $(DOCKER_REPOSITORY)

    - task: ECRPushImage@1
      inputs:
        awsCredentails: $(aws_ecr_service_connection)
        regionName: $(AWS_REGION)
        imageSource: 'gajisoftidentityapi'
        sourceImageName: '$(DOCKER_REPOSITORY)'
        sourceImageTag: $(Build.BuildId)
        pushTag: latest
        repositoryName: $(DOCKER_REPOSITORY_NAME)
```

It fails when I am pushing my images to ECR.

**Permissions to ECR from my ECR User**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:PutImageTagMutability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:TagResource",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:eu-north-1:xxxxxx:repository/xxxxx-xxx"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:CreateRepository",
                "ecr:DescribeRegistry",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the **`ECRPushImage@1`** task, the value of '**`imageSource`**' (**Image Identity**) can be either '**`imagename`**' or '**`imageid`**'. It does not receive other values.

- When you want to push the Docker image by using **Image Name** and **Image Tag**, you should select '**`imagename`**' option.
- If you want to use **Image ID** to push the Docker image, select '**`imageid`**' option.

For more details, you can reference the Amazon documentation "[**Amazon ECR Push task**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/ecr-pushimage.html)"

---

So, for your case, since you want to use **Image Name** and **Image Tag** to push the Docker image, you can configure the **`ECRPushImage@1`** task like as below in your pipeline.

```yaml
    - task: ECRPushImage@1
      displayName: 'Push Image to ECR'
      inputs:
       awsCredentials: {AWS Service Connection}
       regionName: {AWS Region}
       imageSource: imagename
       sourceImageName: {Source Image Name}
       sourceImageTag: {Source Image Tag}
       repositoryName: {Target Repository Name}
       pushTag: {Target Repository Tag}
```

---